# SQL Continuous Date Ranges Previously Grouped Data

Tags: sql, loops, common-table-expression

I'm working with a data extract that represents claims data for a population. The ultimate goal is to be able to associate specific claims to unique encounters. The way we'd define an encounter is a string of claims that are continuous, or within the same range; meaning the claim-to date is followed up by a claim-from date immediately after, or has an identical to & from date as another claim. However, because there is no key that actually indicates that a group of claims represent a specific encounter, we have to implement logic that does this for us.

For the sake of this example, we've already grouped the data by Patient & Facility.

```
CREATE TABLE #BillingData (
ClaimID VARCHAR(MAX)
,Patient VARCHAR(MAX)
,Facility VARCHAR(MAX)
,ClaimFromDate DATE
,ClaimToDate DATE
,GroupID VARCHAR(MAX)
)

INSERT INTO #BillingData
VALUES
('Claim1','JOHN DOE','NURSING HOME','2000-01-01','2000-01-01','1')
,('Claim2','JOHN DOE','NURSING HOME','2000-01-01','2000-01-31','1')
,('Claim3','JOHN DOE','NURSING HOME','2000-01-01','2000-01-31','1')
,('Claim4','JOHN DOE','NURSING HOME','2000-01-01','2000-01-31','1')
,('Claim5','JOHN DOE','NURSING HOME','2000-02-01','2000-02-29','1')
,('Claim6','JOHN DOE','NURSING HOME','2000-03-01','2000-03-31','1')
,('Claim7','JOHN DOE','NURSING HOME','2000-04-01','2000-04-30','1')
,('Claim8','JOHN DOE','NURSING HOME','2000-08-01','2000-08-31','1')
,('Claim9','JOHN DOE','NURSING HOME','2000-09-01','2000-09-30','1')
,('Claim10','JANE DOE','HOME HEALTH','2000-02-01','2000-02-29','2')
,('Claim11','JANE DOE','HOME HEALTH','2000-03-01','2000-03-31','2')
,('Claim11','JANE DOE','HOME HEALTH','2000-03-01','2000-03-31','2')
```

What'd I'd like to see ultimately is an encounter ID. This is how the individual claims should be placed into encounter IDs:

Claims 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 are in Encounter 1.1; 
Claims 8,9 are in Encounter 1.2; 
Claims 10,11 are in Encounter 2.1

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What's your DBMS?

Comment: We're using MS SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the gaps, i.e. the current start date is greater than any previous end date (plus one day)

```
with gaps as
 (
   select *,
      case
        when max(ClaimToDate) -- max previous end date
             over (partition by Patient, Facility
                   order by ClaimFromDate, ClaimID
                   rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding)
            < dateadd(day,-1,ClaimFromDate) -- compare to current start date 
        then 1 -- gap
        else 0 -- overlapping ranges
      end as flag
   from #BillingData
 )
select *,
   sum(flag) -- cumulative sum over 0/1 to create encounter number 
   over (partition by Patient, Facility
         order by ClaimFromDate, ClaimID
         rows unbounded preceding) +1 as encounter
from gaps
order by GroupID, encounter, ClaimFromDate
```

See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=9f0eb0fc89d4b106077d94c75f93264d)

Comment: Genius. Thanks for the quick response. Worked perfect!